# SSIS Sequence Container will not fail

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I have created an SSIS solution that makes use of Sequence Containers.

The point of the SSIS package is this. Every 3rd and 5th business day I need to create folders and copy files into them. On the 3rd business day files are copied to the respective 3rd business day folders. Likewise on the 5th business day. These folders and files are housed in a parent folder that is named yyyymm i.e. 201411. The folder structure for both is a little odd but that is beyond my control and not the issue.

I could not figure out how to count business days so the way I was hoping to design the SSIS package so that a single SSIS package could accomplish both is by using Success/Failure toggles precedence constraints.

I designed the flow so that the first time the package is run it creates the Day3 folders and then copies the files. The second time it is ran the day3 package will note that the Day3 folders have been created and fail. That failure is intended. I want the failure of the package to effect the parent sequence container and for the sequence container to fail entirely. After this failure I want the package to continue along the failure constraint, creating the Day5 folders and copying those files.

The issue is the task fails as desired, however this stops the package entirely. The flow does not continue along the failure constraint and perform the Day5 function. I have tried adjusting properties in the packages, sequence containers and also adjusting the propagate System variable as I saw suggested via internet searches but I cannot get the intended flow to work.

There is probably a better way to do this entire process and I am open to suggestions, but the real purpose of this query is to figure out how to get the Sequence container to fail as a whole and for the package to continue performing the Day5 functions.

3rd Business Day
[image: Third]

5th Business Day
[image: 5th]

SSIS Package
[image]

Desired Result. Sequence container fails if a child package fails within it.
[image: SSISFAIL]

In response to a comment below. I tried to setup a Boolean constraint but this did not work either. Not sure if I did this correctly.
[image: Boolean]

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way of doing this would be to set a boolean variable on the Package level and as soon as the Day3 would fail, this would be set to False. On the Failure precedence constraint, you would check to see the value of this variable. If the value of the variable is FALSE (or true) then you can proceed with the Day5 Container, otherwise ignore it.

The other thing that comes to my mind, can you toggle the AND/OR on the precedence constraints after Day 3 container. Just wanted to check and see if that might change the behavior.

Comment: I tried to add Boolean logic to the constraint and toggled AND/OR, but still can't get the Sequence container to fail.

Comment: Add a script task (After Day 3 Container) and explicitly turn the boolean variable to False. The precedence constraint between these 2 should be Failure I believe. I will investigate this further and get back to you in some time. In the mean time, please try this solution.

Comment: If you could add an image that'd be helpful. I'm a little confused what goes where.